# MySQL calculate yyyy-mm-dd to days

Tags: mysql, sql, select, date-formatting

I currently have a column that shows the last time a user accessed a specific environment and the format is `2015-01-26 15:35:45`  - I need to be able to somehow calculate / convert the format, so I can determine if the user has accessed the environment in the last 45 days, using `current_date` as the date to calculate from.

Comment: What is the column's data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DATE_SUB` to subtract 45 days from current date and compare that with values in your field i.e.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
```

which gives `2015-08-09 14:41:55` when executed on `2015-09-23 14:41:55`, hence your query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE last_login_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
```

### OR

You can use `DATEDIFF` to subtract two dates, this will return the difference in days between the given dates

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), '2015-09-01')
```

which gives `21` i.e. 2015-09-01 is 21 days before current date. So your query should look like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_login_dt) >= 45
```

assuming that name of your field with last login date is `last_login_dt`, please change as required

Comment: Thanks mynawaz, This worked out perfectly!  I want to thank everyone who posted solutions. You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string to a date, and then use [`datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to find the days between then and `NOW()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(last_login, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-%s')) >= 45
```